# Open word from excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I can't open Word from Excel macro (Office XP). If I use this code, it will stop on line `Set wdDoc = wordapp.Documents.Open(polozka.ShortPath)` and program freezes. If I use `Set wdDoc = GetObject(polozka.ShortPath)` instead of this line, program stops here `With wdDoc.Selection` with error:

> "Object doesn't support this property"

```
Dim wordapp As Word.Application
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set files = fso.GetFolder("C:\path").Files       
Set wordapp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

For Each polozka In files
    Set wdDoc = wordapp.Documents.Open(polozka.ShortPath)
    wordapp.Visible = True
    With wdDoc.Selection
        .HomeKey Unit:=6
        .Find.Text = "Název (typ):"
        .Find.Wrap = wdFindContinue
        ...
    End With
    ...
    wordapp.Quit
    Set wordapp = Nothing    
Next
```

Answer (score 15):

You have to declare your variable `as Object` like below:

```
Dim Paragraphe As Object, WordApp As Object, WordDoc As Object
```

And to use the doc:

```
File= "D:\path"
'Word session creation 
Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
'word will be closed while running
WordApp.Visible = False
'open the .doc file 
Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(File)
```

And to close the application:

```
WordDoc.Close
WordApp.Quit
Set WordDoc = Nothing
Set WordApp = Nothing
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: thanks, now I can open document in first way, but still program stops here `With wdDoc.Selection` with "Object doesn't support this property or method" error

Comment: I found solution. Change this row `With wdDoc.Selection` to this `With wordapp.Selection` solved it. But still I don't know, why I can't work with `wdDoc` object

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem with excel not recognizing the word.application command and other word Objects.  If you want those objects to be recognized by excel you will need to select Tools>References... in the Visual Basic editor.  When you select References a window will populate, go down through the list until you find Microsoft Word x.0 Object Library.  Select the check box, this will allow excel to now recognize word commands.  You can also change the priority level of that Object Library to make it easier to find next time.

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub substitute()  
'  
' substitute Macro 
' 
' Note: In Excel VBA, in tools -> references: Enable Microsoft Word 12.0 0bject  
'  
Dim FindStr As String  
Dim ReplaceStr As String  
Dim path_src As String  
Dim path_dest As String  

' Define word object  
Dim WA As Object  

Dim cs As Worksheet  
Dim Idx As Integer  

' Data worksheet "Data" col A find text, Col B replace text  
Set cs = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")  

Set WA = CreateObject("Word.Application")  

WA.Visible = True  

path_src = "C:\Temp\data.docx"  
path_dest = "C:\Temp\data_out.docx"  

WA.documents.Open (path_src)  

' Set word object active  
WA.Activate  

' Optional, use Idx to limit loop iterations  
Idx = 1  
Do While ((Len(cs.Cells(Idx, 1).Value) > 1) And (Idx < 100))  
'  
  FindStr = cs.Cells(Idx, 1).Value  
  ReplaceStr = cs.Cells(Idx, 2).Value  
  With WA  
    .Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory  
    .Selection.Find.ClearFormatting  
    .Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting  
    With .Selection.Find  
        .Text = FindStr  
        .Replacement.Text = ReplaceStr  
        .Forward = True  
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk  
        .Format = False  
        .MatchCase = False  
        .MatchWholeWord = False  
        .MatchWildcards = False  
        .MatchSoundsLike = False  
        .MatchAllWordForms = False  
    End With  

    .Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll  
   End With  
   Idx = Idx + 1  
Loop  
WA.Application.ActiveDocument.SaveAs path_dest  
WA.documents.Close  

Set WA = Nothing  

End Sub
```

Comment: Please, format your code in a correct way. [Read the SO markdown online help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).